# Prove that if $A_{n}$ belongs to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ for each $n \geq 1$, then $\bigcap^\infty_{n = 1} A_{n} \in \mathcal{F}$

Tags: measure-theory

I am going over properties of sigma-algebras but am struggling how to go about proving certain properties or conditions. I would be able to do this if it was talking about the union, but the intersection I am unsure of.

Comment: The definition of sigma algebra gives you closure under infinite unions and under complements, so, you use those properties to prove closure under infinite intersections.

Comment: You’ve misstated the result. It should read: Prove that if $A_n$ belongs to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ for each $n\ge 1$, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal{F}$. ‘For each $n\ge 1$, $\bigcap{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal{F}$’ makes no sense.

Comment: Apolgies Brian, thank you for pointing that out. I will ammend that now.

Comment: If people are downvoting this question I would appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is worth emphasizing the definition of $\sigma$-algebra.

**Definition**

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty set, where $2^{\Omega}$ indicates its power set. We say that a class of subsets $\mathcal{F}$ of $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra iff

- $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$,
- If $A\in\mathcal{F}$, then $A^{c}\in\mathcal{F}$,
- If $A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}$ is a countable collection of sets, then one has that
  \begin{align*}
  \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}
  \end{align*}

**Solution**

Thus, if $A_{n}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$, then $A^{c}_{n}$ also belongs to $\mathcal{F}$.

According to the countable union property, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A^{c}_{n}\in\mathcal{F} \Rightarrow\left[\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A^{c}_{n}\right]^{c} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, is that DeMorgans law? Or the DeMorgan identity? I forget the specific terminology.

Comment: It is the DeMorgan law indeed.

Comment: Ah yes that makes much more sense now. Because I knew that the countable union property existed but I couldn't figure how to relate it with interesections. When you take the complement of the union of complements in the last equation of your answer, that is also suitable because even though the union is in $\mathcal{F}$, the complement of the union is also in $\mathcal{F}$ and therefore still a $\sigma$-algebra, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The complement of the union is the intersection of the complements. Since we are dealing with $\sigma$-algebras, the complement lies in $\mathcal{F}$ and we are done.

Comment: The intersection of the complements?

Comment: This is what I meant

$$(A\cup B)^{c} = A^{c}\cap B^{c}$$